# How to store bagels?

Tags: baking, storage-method, bread

I've seen conflicting advice on how to store bagels.

I make 6 at a time, for use over the course of a week (or less).

Should I store the ones I'm planning on eating tomorrow and the day after differently than the rest?

I know that bagels are best eaten within a day, but I'm not going to make fresh ones daily. I'm looking for what storage method will help the bagel maintain the best quality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would keep the one that you are eating the next day out.  I would then freeze the rest of them.

If you like them warm, you could freeze them wrapped in foil.  Before eating pop them in a toaster oven until gently warmed through.

If not I'd freeze individually until solid then put in a bag to prevent your frozen bagels from sticking together, then thaw overnight (if eating in the morning) or in the morning (if eating for a mid-day meal) to eat.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some detail to the excellent accepted answer:

Bagels will keep for months in the freezer if wrapped in foil and bagged in small groups in a freezer bag.

In my frequent experience, the best way to reheat them is to place them in a 150C/300F oven, still frozen and wrapped in foil, for about 20 minutes.